# Using a fallback image in angular for webp

Tags: html, angular, typescript, webp, image-fallback

```
<img src=${imageUrlWebp} onerror="this.error=null;this.src=${imageUrl}" width="700" height="110"/>
```

Does this method of using fallback images in angular work in all the browsers.It seems to work in browser but not sure how to check in browsers which don't support webp. I know that they is another method something like this

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="img/awesomeWebPImage.webp" type="image/webp">
  <source srcset="img/creakyOldJPEG.jpg" type="image/jpeg"> 
  <img src="img/creakyOldJPEG.jpg" alt="Alt Text!">
</picture>
```

But this doesn't seem to work properly as I am appending this snippet to html from a typescript file and always renders the src i give in img tag.

So can anyone tell if the first method is correct and any pointers on how to check if fallback is working properly in browsers which don't support webp

Comment: The only browser you might have issues with is `Safari` with webp. Otherwise Angular itself isn't supported on older browsers anyway. https://angular.io/guide/browser-support and https://caniuse.com/?search=webp

Comment: I know I would have problems with safari on systems running anything lower than macOS Big Sur and IE.....but I want to be sure that my fallback image runs on it

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn would onerror event be triggered when webp image is not supported by that particular browser

Comment: I am not sure..